# Netty: Peer-to-peer like application

Tags: netty, nio

First I have to say that the answer to my question might already be out there. (It might even be possible that I just used the wrong search terms) Maybe I just overlooked it. I want to apologize in advance if that is the case.

I'm new to netty so I might have missed something that should be obvious. For all my questions I'd be happy for just a hint in the right direction.

What I'm trying to build:

- central entity: every other instance of my program starts by connecting to this entity. It gathers information about active instances and tells the existing ones about the new one (and vice versa). The central entity is for passing commands. Instances can report to it or send a status information (Status Information won't go to all other instances but to an user-controlled-instance)
- Every instance connects to all other instances. instances run different modules (each module is part of the over all data processing. as processing is done in different steps I'll just use numbers for the modules instead of their names and what exactly they are supposed to do). data has to be passed from module 1 to module 2 to module 3 etc. Data from Instance with module 1 is passed to an instance running module 2 directly. It is possible that data from instance1 has to go to instance 3 or instance 4 (depending on the data). Every 1-10 seconds there will be data to be passed for the next step in the process (almost 10 seconds for the first step and all following steps have to finish their portion before the next chunk of data arrives - just to give an impression of the scenario). Some of the Data might even have to skip a Step in the process (Depending on the specific Data in the chunk).

I hope that I got all necessary info gathered here.

All this leads me to multiple Questions:

1. Would it be better to use UDP for data-transfer or TCP connections? (traffic has to be encrypted. I require a way to verify it has not been altered. I guess it does not depend on the protocol used. Maybe it is easier or "more secure" if I use TCP.)
2. From what I've read and seen in examples it is always a simple client-server architecture. the server receives messages and relays them to all client. For my scenario I could not yet figure out how it should be done (best). Some messages have to be passed to all clients. Some just have to reach specific clients. I could not yet find a good answer on how to implement something like this. (I got a few ideas but 0 experience and I'm just finding new ideas but no answers. And I'd like to find something not just working caused by my lack of knowledge.)

Comment: First, have a look at [Akka](http://akka.io/). It's a framework for distributed, message-based architectures that uses Netty underneath the hood. Second, your question isn't really SO format, so you probably won't get much attention.

Comment: Did not know about Akka. Thanks for the hint.